# Airflow schedule order

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a few airflow tasks, I want to make sure a specific task executes always as the last task in my DAG. There might be some tasks that will be skipped depending on the input.

```
this_will_run_for_sure_1 = DummyOperator()
this_will_run_for_sure_2 = DummyOperator()
this_might_not_run_1 = DummyOperator() # Can run in parallel with this_will_run_for_sure_1 
this_might_not_run_2 = DummyOperator() # Can run only after this_will_run_for_sure_2 and this_might_not_run_1 finished
final_task = DummyOperator()
```

How could be this set up with bitwise operators? I was thinking something like:

```
this_will_run_for_sure_1 >> this_will_run_for_sure_2
this_might_not_run_1 >> this_might_not_run_2
[this_will_run_for_sure_2, this_might_not_run_2] >> final_task
```

But this does not work as expected, if `this_might_not_run_1` does not start because the input does not have the required data for it to start, it won't get to final task. Any help on this is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing also:

```
this_will_run_for_sure_2 >> this_might_not_run_2
```

This should resolve your issue:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator


@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1)
)
def example():
    this_will_run_for_sure_1 = DummyOperator(task_id='this_will_run_for_sure_1')
    this_will_run_for_sure_2 = DummyOperator(task_id='this_will_run_for_sure_2')
    this_might_not_run_1 = DummyOperator(task_id='this_might_not_run_1') # Can run in parallel with this_will_run_for_sure_1
    this_might_not_run_2 = DummyOperator(task_id='this_might_not_run_2') # Can run only after this_will_run_for_sure_2 and this_might_not_run_1 finished
    final_task = DummyOperator(task_id='final_task')

    this_will_run_for_sure_1 >> this_will_run_for_sure_2 >> this_might_not_run_2
    this_might_not_run_1 >> this_might_not_run_2
    [this_will_run_for_sure_2, this_might_not_run_2] >> final_task


dag = example()
```

Example:
[image]